# File name after MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage

Tags: java, android, image, rename

I am using `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(ContentResolver cr, String imagePath, String name, String description)` function to insert a newly created image into gallery. System is naming the file by default, but it's diferent than names of pictures taken by orginal app (Time stamp). Is there easy way to set it up?

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this

```
Uri u;
File fi = new File("/sdcard/tmp");
try {
    u = Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), fi.getAbsolutePath(), null, null));
    imageSaveName1 = u.toString();

}
```

imageSaveName1 looks something like "content://media/external/images/media/159"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html), `insertImage` returns the URL:

> **Returns**
>       The URL to the newly created image

Did it not work?

Comment: That's the URL, not the file name.

Answer (score 0):

InsertImage, or just inserting ContentValues and writing to the uri, results in a file name of the date's long value.

For example I present my situation. Inserting content values where the mime type is specified as image/gif, and then writing to the resulting uri, results in a file xxxxxxxxx.jpg. The specified mime type is ignored entirely. The resulting gif image in the MediaStore does not animate and is essentially broken being displayed as a standard jpeg.

At this point I see no way to insert content values and specify a specific filename after writing to the resulting uri via a stream. Specifying the mime type in MediaScannerConnection does not help either.