# MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage won't save image

Tags: android, image, save

I need to save image to internal storage from bitmap and here is the code I am using

```
        String imagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            bitmap,
            "demo_image",
            "demo_image"
        );
```

but that does absolutely nothing and also the imagePath is null.

Comment: Post some more code, how and where are you using?

Comment: Do research before asking a question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3974630/5550161

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70056101/12272687